# SunPKCS11 and PKCS11 middleware

Tags: pkcs#11

I am trying to consume a middleware for calculating Hash values. 
The code is as given below:

```
    Provider provider = new sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11("D:\\PKI\\Middleware\\pkcs.cfg");
    Security.addProvider(provider);
```

My pkcs.cfg file looks like this:

```
name=RANDOM
slot=0
library=D:\PKI\Middleware\bin\PKCS11Library.dll.
```

When I try to run the above code the JVM crashes instantly with the below crash report.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

try  putting in a bytearrayinputstream

```
String pkcs11config1 = "name=Athenaslot1\nlibrary=C:\WINDOWS\system32\asepkcs.dll";
byte[] pkcs11configBytes1 =pkcs11config1.getBytes();
ByteArrayInputStream configStream1 = new ByteArrayInputStream(pkcs11configBytes1);
etpkcs11 = new SunPKCS11(configStream1);
Security.addProvider(etpkcs11);
```